# Tutorial Django Documentation part 1. Requests and responses

Tags: python, django

I'm going through the django documentation tutorial and i've hit a wall pretty early. The rundown is i'm trying to set up a simple server with django then dev a polls taking app. I've followed the steps in detail (as far as I can tell) and i'm unable to complete the last part. Opening the link bellow to see a print out of the polls/views.py code. Any help will be appreciated by this confused newbie. Thank you much.

I'm unable to access the link provided to check if my code is working.[this is the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfhru.png)

This is my current tree;

```
  mysite
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── settings.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   └── wsgi.cpython-37.pyc
├── asgi.py
├── settings.py
├── urls.py
└── wsgi.py
```

This is my polls/urls.py;

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlspatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

This error comes up when I run it;

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/trevorhegarty/my_code/code.acad/tutorialDJ/mysite/polls/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

This is mysite/urls.py;

```
    from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Which throws this at me;

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/trevorhegarty/my_code/code.acad/tutorialDJ/mysite/mysite/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'polls'
```

When I run  in terminal it shoots back this code in the terminal;

```
˚
```

This is my polls folder;

```
    .
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   └── views.cpython-37.pyc
├── admin.py
├── apps.py
├── migrations
│   └── __init__.py
├── models.py
├── tests.py
├── urls.py
└── views.py
```

Comment: There's no app in your project tree, you should start from the beginning and create it at first by `python manage.py startapp polls`

Comment: @Lothric it looks like that directory listing is from `mysite/mysite/`, and I believe your comment assumes it's the listing of `mysite/`.

Answer (score 0):

You're very much on the right track!

There's one step missing from this iteration of the Django tutorial. When you run the startapp command, Django creates a new application with some boilerplate code but it doesn't add it to your INSTALLED_APPS.

In settings.py, find your INSTALLED_APPS and add polls to the end of that list.

Comment: I went in and added it to INSTALLED_APPS. Close terminal then ran it again and it still sent me the same error. It will probably be smart to start from square one?

Comment: @TheMeanCheese can you post the file tree of the `polls` folder?

Comment: When I run <mysite/urls.py> it returns a ModelNotFoundError.